# Derivative of a differentiable function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $f$ is a differentiable function over $[a,b]$ and $f'(a)<0$, $f'(b)>0$. Prove that exist $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$.

I can see $f$ is a differentiable so it is continuous too, but its derivative need not be continuous, so I cannot use the the intermediate value theorem here. Is there some way to prove it? Thank you for help.

Note: I cannot use  Darboux theorem too, because this theorem is studied at the next lesson.

Comment: Use Darboux's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: in my textbook, Darboux theorem is studied after this problem, so i cannot use it :(

Comment: What you're being asked to show is basically Darboux's theorem. I would suggest having a look at a proof of that theorem, either on wikipedia or in your textbook. Hopefully they only use techniques you're allowed to use.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable on $[a,b]$ the derivative may or may not be continuous in this interval. Since $f'(a)<0$ and $f'(b)>0$, as the derivative changes sign so $f(x)$ cannot be monotonic. Hence, $f(x)$ will have at least one local max or one local min (say) at $x=c\in[a,b]$ and it is here $f'(c)=0.$ At $x=c$, $f'(x)$ need not be continuous.

Comment: the derivative $f'(x)$ can be not continuous, you can check some examples in wikipedia.

Comment: @Hoang, your concern is correct, you are right. I have edited my answer where I drop IVT now.